# Python events and delegates

Tags: python, class, events, methods, delegates

This is probably a basic question but I am new to programming. I am working with a third party python code and it provides a class with event and event delegates. The syntax for the events and event delegates are follows:

```
    public Delegate Sub RequestEventDelegate (request As MDNPRequest, _
      response as MDNPResponseParser)

    public Event RequestEvent As MDNPRequest.RequestEventDelegate
```

I wrote the following code to subcribe to the event but is not working. I do not know what I am
   doing wrong.

```
    Mreq = MDNPRequest()
    Mreq.RequestEvent += Mreq.RequestEventDelegate(handleResponseEvent)

    def handleResponseEvent (request, response):
        print ' event fired'
```

I am adding the two lines of code to the end of a function that opens up the communication channel. I also tested adding the two lines of code to a function that send a poll on the communication channel. In the second scenario the event fires and every time I execute the polling function. Does this defeat the purpose of event subscription?

---

I think that my problem maybe due to different functions creating instances of the same class. I would like to consolidate some of the functions into a class using the outline shown below. Method1 creates an instance 'a' of a class1 that I would like the other methods in myClass to use. I tried using a class variable which I set to a class1 instance but this is not working. I reference the class variable using the class name for example myClass.variable.somemethod from class1 but I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. What is the best approach so that all methods in myClass can have access to a? Eventually I would like to call myClass from another module.

```
    from file1 import *

    myClass:

       class_variable = class1() # class1 from file1

       def __init__(self)
       ...

       def Method1(self, argument list):
         # this method instantiates a  
          ...
          a = class1() 

       def Method2 (self):
          ...
          a.class1method1
          ...

       def Method3 (self):
          ...
          a.class1method2
          ...
```

Comment: Is this IronPython, and C# syntax you're trying to match up to? Or something different?

Comment: @abarnert I am trying to match VB.

Comment: Thanks. In general, it helps to put that information in the question—and, even more so, to put a link to where the information comes from. In this case, none of that may be relevant to your problem, but it never hurts.

Comment: "I think that my problem maybe due to different functions creating instances of the same class." That shouldn't be a problem, unless you're only registering for events on one instance rather than all of them, or something similar. Without seeing your code, I have no idea if you are. More generally, if you show us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that's sufficient to demonstrate your problem, it'll be a lot easier to find what you're doing wrong, rather than having to guess what you might have done wrong.

Comment: Also, in your latest code, you're just referencing the methods (e.g., `a.class1method`); you're never calling them anywhere (`a.class1method()`). If that's the same in your real code, it could easily explain why things aren't working the way you expected.

Comment: As a side note, it's easier to read your code if you use a consistent capitalization style, to make it obvious what's a class, what's a variable, what's a function, etc. You can use the standard Python style from [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (`MyClass`, `mymodule`, `my_variable`, `my_function`), or the .NET style, or whatever… just pick one and be consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your later edits, I suspect that you're missing the fundamentals of how classes work in Python. You may want to read through [the tutorial chapter](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html), or maybe search for a friendlier/more detailed tutorial.

In particular:

> I would like to consolidate some of the functions into a class using the outline shown below. Method1 creates an instance 'a' of a class1 that I would like the other methods in myClass to use. I tried using a class variable which I set to a class1 instance but this is not working.

That's not the way to do it. Class attributes, like your `class_variable`, are created at class creation time (that is, generally, as soon as you `import` the module or run the script), not instance creation time. If you want something created when instances of your class are created, you use instance attributes, not class attributes, and you set them in the `__init__` method. In your case, you don't want the instance created until `Method1` is called on an instance—again, that means you use an instance attribute; you just do it inside `Method1` rather than `__init__`.

Also, class attributes are shared by all instances of the class; instance attributes, each instance has its own one. Thing about dogs: each dog has its own tail, there's not one tail shared by all dogs, so `tail` is an instance attribute. Often, in simple scripts, you don't notice the difference, because you only happen to ever create one instance of the class. But if you can't figure out the difference practically, think about it conceptually (like the `Dog` example)—and if you still can't figure it out, you almost always want an instance attribute.

> I reference the class variable using the class name for example myClass.variable.somemethod from class1 but I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

Most likely this is because `class1` is a COM/interop or .NET class, and you're trying to create and use it before doing any of the relevant setup, which is only happening because you're trying to do it as soon as you `import` the module/run the script. If so, if you create it when you actually intended to, there won't be a problem.

> What is the best approach so that all methods in myClass can have access to a?

Create an instance attribute in `Method1`, like this:

```
def Method1(self, argument list):
    # this method instantiates a  
     ...
    self.a = class1()
```

And then use it the same way:

```
def Method2 (self):
     ...
    self.a.class1method1()
     ...
```

Just doing `a = whatever` just creates a local variable that goes away at the end of the method. Even if it happens to have the same name as a class attribute, instance attribute, or global, you're still creating a new local variable, not modifying the thing you want to modify. Unlike some other languages, Python requires you to be explicit about what you're trying to overwrite—`self.a` for an instance attribute, `myClass.a` for a class attribute, etc.—so you don't do it by accident.

Also, note the parentheses at the end of that last expression. If you want to call a function or method, you need parentheses; otherwise, you're just referencing the method itself as a value.

---

> Eventually I would like to call myClass from another module.

I'm not sure what you mean by "class myClass". When you call a class, that constructs a new instance of the class. You can then call that instance's methods the same way you would any other object. It doesn't matter what module it was defined in (except that you obviously have to write `my_instance = mymodule.MyClass()`).

Look at how you use the standard library; it's exactly the same. For example, if you `import csv`, you can construct a [`DictWriter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) by writing `my_writer = csv.DictWriter(my_file)`. And then you call its methods by writing `my_writer.writerow(my_row)`. Once you've constructed it, it doesn't matter what module it came from.

---

One more thing:

You've tried to define a class like this:

```
myClass:
```

You obviously can't do that; you need the `class` keyword. But also, in Python 2.x, you always want to give base classes, using `object` if you don't need anything else. Otherwise, you get an old-style class, which causes all kinds of weird quirks and limitations that you don't want to learn about and have to debug. So:

```
class myClass(object):
```

Comment: @abarnet Thank you for input. I was not aware that one could instatiate a class outside __init__ and that is the reason for my attempt to use a class variable. I have some test code running now.

Comment: @CarlosBustamante: What do you mean by "instantiate a class outside `__init__`"? Instantiating a class is just the "my_object = myClass()` part, which never happens inside `__init__`. (Well, it could happen inside the `__init__` of some _other_ class.) Did you mean "add an instance variable? That's the one that tends to surprise people coming from languages like Java. In Python, you can add new variables to any object (except objects of some builtin types) at any time—even from completely outside the class.

Comment: @abarnet I was thinking that instance variables had to be defined within __init__. As you pointed out instance variables can be assigned at any time.

Answer (score 2):

If this is actually your code:

```
Mreq.RequestEvent += Mreq.RequestEventDelegate(handleResponseEvent)

def handleRequestEvent (request, response):
    print ' event fired'
```

… `handleResponseEvent` is not the same thing as `handleRequestEvent`.

---

As a side note, you almost never need to create an explicit delegate. It's sometimes a useful optimization, but it's one more thing you can get wrong, and one more thing that can disguise useful debugging information when you do, so it's usually simpler to write the code without it first, and only add wrap it as a delegate after it's working, if you find yourself creating a whole lot of them and want to save some memory.